# Reducing the visibility of a static method

Tags: java, inheritance, information-hiding

I know that a child cannot reduce the visibility of a non-static method and I understand why it is so.

I've read however that "static method can be hidden through its redeclaration". I however do not understand how this could be achieved in Java.

Is this really possible? If yes, how to do that (code example) and why was it introduced (it seems to contradict the principle of non-reducing the visibility of the interface)?

Comment: Do you have a reference/link for the 2nd statement?

Comment: Unless I am getting this wrong, it could very well mean override the static method. When you override, you change only the body of the method - everything else i.e. the return type, method name, and signature remain the same. This is sort or redeclaration. Overloading should also work.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Unfortunately no, it comes from the university materials I've come by and these aren't written in English.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange case of static method override in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297252/strange-case-of-static-method-override-in-java)

Comment: @hagubear: you can't "override" a static method.

Comment: Indeed, Eclipse doesn't allow me to override it, treating it the same way as in case of non-static method. So it is not Eclipse, it is a Java restriction, right?

Comment: @infoholic_anonymous      Overload then - http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/can-we-overload-or-override-static-methods-in-java/  Also, stop saying "Eclipse doesn't let me override/overload..." Eclipse is a tool. You will have same issue even if you use IntelliJ, Notepad++, whatever. It is a Java Language-related issue. Tools are tools.

Comment: @hagubear: I didn't mean for you to delete your [recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26963891/522444) to the other question, rather to just add an explanation to it. Explanations and concepts are valuable, often more so than code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels       I saw a comment which made my effort useless anyway - also, let's not confuse this OP here as he will think "I got an answer and it got deleted?" lol

Comment: @hagubear: a correct answer is much better than a comment. Please fix it so I can up-vote it.

Comment: @infoholic_anonymous    I believe your question has probably been addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods). This might not be identical, but very close to your issue.

Comment: @hagubear Thanks for the link. I guess an excerpt from it solves the question and is what the author of the statement in question meant. Here is the solution: "We can declare static methods with same signature in subclass, but it is not considered overriding as there won’t be any run-time polymorphism. Hence the answer is ‘No’.
If a derived class defines a static method with same signature as a static method in base class, the method in the derived class hides the method in the base class."

Comment: @hagubear so maybe you could write a corresponding answer to it so that the question could be marked as solved?

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is: no, it is not possible. You have mixed up some terminology. *Hiding* has nothing to do with *accessibility* (which is what you are really asking about, not *visibility*, which is related to *scope* and *shadowing* and is discussed in [Chapter 6 of the Java Language Specification (JLS)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html)).

Now for the longer answer. The term *overriding* applies to instance methods, while the term *hiding* applies to class (`static`) methods. From the [Java Tutorial topic Overriding and Hiding Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html):

> The distinction between hiding a static method and overriding an instance method has important implications:
>
> - The version of the overridden instance method that gets invoked is the one in the subclass.
> - The version of the hidden static method that gets invoked depends on whether it is invoked from the superclass or the subclass.

Some of the other answers here provide incorrect examples about method hiding, so let's go back to the JLS, this time to [§8.4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8):

> Methods are overridden or hidden on a signature-by-signature basis.

That is, to override or hide a method in the parent class, the subclass must define a method with the same *signature*—basically, the same number and type of arguments (although generics and type erasure makes the rules a little more complicated than that). There are also rules about return types and `throws` clauses, but those seem irrelevant to this question.

Note that you can define a method in a subclass with the same *name* as a method in the parent class (or in an implemented interface) but with different number or type of arguments. In that case, you are *overloading* the method name and neither overriding nor hiding anything; the subclass method is a new method, pretty much independent of the inherited method(s). (There is an interaction when the compiler has to match methods to method calls, but that's about it.)

Now to your question: the terms *accessibility* and *hiding* (as well as *visibility*) are independent concepts in Java. There is, as you put it, a "principle" that there is simply no way for a subclass to reduce the accessibility of an inherited method. This applies regardless of whether you are overriding an instance method or hiding a class method. From [the JLS §8.4.8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3):

> The access modifier ([§6.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6)) of an overriding or hiding method must provide at least as much access as the overridden or hidden method, as follows:
>
> - If the overridden or hidden method is `public`, then the overriding or hiding method must be `public`; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
> - If the overridden or hidden method is `protected`, then the overriding or hiding method must be `protected` or `public`; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
> - If the overridden or hidden method has default (package) access, then the overriding or hiding method must *not* be `private`; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

In summary, the fact that a `static` method can be hidden has nothing to do with changing the accessibility of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Based on hagubear's valuable comments, it seems that the author of a statement meant hiding a method through *overloading* it with a method having the same declaration.

Quoting this [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/can-we-overload-or-override-static-methods-in-java/):

> We can declare static methods with same signature in subclass, but it
>   is not considered overriding as there won’t be any run-time
>   polymorphism. (...) If a derived class defines a
>   static method with same signature as a static method in base class,
>   the method in the derived class hides the method in the base class.

Thus, defining a method in a child class having exact same declaration effectively hides the original method in child. However, as in case of fields, casting to the parent will restore the original access.

Sample code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        B b = new B();
        A a = b;
        b.f(); // "Access somewhat denied"
        a.f(); // "f()"
    }
}
class A { 
    public static void f() { 
         System.out.println("f()");
    }
}
class B extends A { 
    // *must* be public
    public static void f() { 
         System.out.println("Access somewhat denied");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nicely expressed.  I like this better than my earlier answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

So I created a trivial test; IntelliJ indeed rejected it... and Yes, I know "it's a tool...but one I trust".  In any case, I went to javac, which emitted the same ERROR:

```
Error:(...) java: ...Concrete.java:5: doSomethingStatic() in 
...Concrete cannot override doSomethingStatic() in 
...Base; attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
```

Based on this, and our skepticism in general, I suggest the error is in your documentation.

Below is my sample code, fairly definitive I think.  It barfs at the `protected`.

```
public class Base
{
    public static void doSomethingStatic(){}
}

public class Concrete extends Base
{
    protected static void doSomethingStatic(){}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It can be hidden by an *overloaded* redeclaration in a derived class:

```
class Base
{
    public static void doSomethingStatic(){}
}

class Derived extends Base
{
    public static void doSomethingStatic(String arg){}
}
```

but only hidden to people who try to access it via the derived class.

Comment: This is not an example of hiding anything. The `doSomethingStatic` method in `Derived` does not have the same signature as the method in `Base`--they have different argument lists.

Comment: It is 'hiding' in the sense defined by the JLS, folks. There isn't any other. And that is what the question is about. @TedHopp

Comment: It is **not** "hiding" in the sense of the JLS. From the [JLS §8.4.8.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.2) (emphasis added): _"If a class C declares or inherits a `static` method m, then m is said to hide any method m', **where the signature of m is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m'**, in the superclasses and superinterfaces of C that would otherwise be accessible to code in C."_ In your example, `doSomethingStatic()` in `Base` is still accessible from code in `Derived` because the args are different. Nothing is hidden.