# error annotating a static method with @Override

Tags: java

There is [Why doesn't Java allow overriding of static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods),
which alleges that overriding static methods is not allowed in java. Yet it seems to work in OpenJDK:

Compiling these two classes works when not using `@Override`, but
fails when doing so.
To reproduce this, the file `Parent.java` looks like this.

```
public class Parent {
    public static int getActivity() { return 1; }
}
```

and the file `Child.java` like this:

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    // @Override public static int getActivity() { return 2; } // fails
    public static int getActivity() { return 2; } // works

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        System.out.println((new Child()).getActivity());
    }
}
```

The error is when using `@Override` is

```
$ javac Child.java
Child.java:3: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override public static int getActivity() { return 2; }
```

When removing the `@Override`, the output is `2`, of the `Child` method.

The javac is version `javac 1.7.0_79` of the OpenJDK.

Where is the error?  (the ideal would be to add `@Override` to static
methods, but the answer that this is a bug in the `OpenJDK` or my thinking would be good, too)

Comment: You cant override static method

Comment: Static methods can't be overridden, but they can be redefined. These are two different mechanisms. If you extend a class with static methods, you can redefine a method by defining a method with the same signature in your subclass. Any callers would have to refer to your subclass to get the redefined method. I have used this in project and it works fine.

Comment: @Tobb They cannot be redefined, they can only be hidden (which is what is happening in the example).

Comment: @Kayaman Maybe "redefined" isn't the correct word for it, but in essence that is what one is doing..

Comment: @TheLostMind: that *is* how hiding works though. In Java and C#, hiding can be circumvented by casting to the appropriate type.

Comment: side note - `@override` does a *compile-time* check. So, if a *parent* doesn't define an *instance level* method, this *annotation* will throw an error when used in the child class.

Comment: I don't see a reason to downvote this question, it has all the necessary information to answer it. Upvoted to bring it back to 0.

Comment: *"which alleges that overriding static methods is not allowed in java. Yet it works in OpenJDK"* It works in OpenJDK? Your example proofs, that this is not the case.

Comment: @Tom: what failed was the `@Override`-Annotation. The compilation worked. (I was not aware of the difference between overriding and hiding)

Comment: @NevyanovL: I was not aware of *hiding* vs overriding. Concerning your statement, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14980158/1587329

Comment: @user1587329 It failed due to the problem in overriding the method. The compiler checks every method with this method if it really overrides a method. Due to the missing annotation, no one told you, that you're not overriding anything there. So it was a misinterpretation about the situation and that something like that works in OpenJDK. Can happen :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not [overriding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) anything here... You just defined a function in class `Child` called `getActivity()`, **which is distinct and hides** the function `getActivity()` in class `Parent`.

**UPDATE:** From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297252/strange-case-of-static-method-override-in-java):

> that doesn't mean it is overriding. In this case, it's the rules in [section 8.4.8.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3), "Requirements in Overriding and Hiding":

Comment: *No relation whatsoever* -- This isn't [entirely accurate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297252/strange-case-of-static-method-override-in-java).

Comment: @aioobe agree and corrected, thanks! ;)